# django-registration with password containing special chars

Tags: django, passwords, django-authentication

I would like to create a sign in/registration page. I saw that the default django library does not provide such function (any reason why?), however it seems that the library [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/quickstart.html#) can help me. However, I don't like the default settings for the password's allowed chars: `Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only`. Indeed, I don't see any reason why a website would force the users to have a password without special chars others than `@/./+/-/_`... Can I change this setting so that the user can use any char he wants?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. are you sure it is for password? I believe allowed chars is for usernames

Comment: I'm really stupid. My bad, sorry for that, thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help

Comment: I guess you need to edit your question from password to username.